# How to divide an array into two equal sum subarray values

Tags: javascript, partition

There is a function that implements the greedy algorithm, but in some cases, it does not find the optimal solution.

```
function optimize() {
    var heap = new Heap();

  const a = [];
  const b = [];
  items
    .map((value, id ) => ({ value, id: `drag${id}` }))
    .sort((A, B) => B.value - A.value)
    .forEach((el) => {
      if (sum(a) < sum(b)) {
        a.push(el.value);
        document.getElementById('machine1').appendChild(document.getElementById(el.id));
      } else {
        b.push(el.value);
        document.getElementById('machine2').appendChild(document.getElementById(el.id));
      }
    })
  calcAll();
}
```

How can I upgrade it so that it is accurate?

Some examples:

[image]

The function divides by the sums 179 and 181, but if you move 28 and 4 from the left heap to the right, and 31 to the right, then you get equal amounts, which means that the solution is not accurate.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Comment: please add data as text, not as picture.

Comment: data: 39,32,31,28,25,20,4,4,25,28,28,96